# Subtypes of Explict cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I come to know that there are additional 4 cursor type as follows. I have refereed this link http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/sql-server-different-types-of-cursors

1. Static Cursors
2. Dynamic Cursors
3. Forward Only Cursors
4. Keyset Driven Cursors

So I want to know that whether these additional four types of cursors are types of Explicit Cursor or not ? or from where they are derived from ?

Comment: `Keyset Driven Cursors` . I am not aware of any such cursors atleast in Oracle. Seems you are mixing `SQL Server` with `Oracle`.

Comment: @XING I need answer related to SQL Only. Not related to Oracle.

Comment: You had tagged your question to `PLSQL` and `PLSQL` is Oracle.

Comment: @XING Thanks. Correction made in tags

Comment: The first link also refers to a question about Oracle. You cannot implicitly declare a cursor in SQL Server.

Comment: @GarethD Ok. I was not aware about it. Thanks for information

Comment: @GarethD Correction made in question

Comment: What, in your mind, is an "explicit cursor"? All cursors are explicit in T-SQL. You could call client-side cursors "implicit", but even so, all cursor types are available in a [`DECLARE CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) statement, so this distinction doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Don't waste your time studying functionality that is both discouraged (because it is abused and often poorly coded), rarely used, and generally poorly suited to most sql solutions. Master efficient set-based query techniques first.

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen is correct; the word "Explicit" doesn't carry much meaning here. There are server-side API cursors, but unless you are going to break out the ole' C++ compiler and create a new connection library, we'll ignore those.

SQL Server T-SQL has two distinct types of syntax for declaring cursors, and it is important to observer the distinction because they cannot be mixed. One is the ANSI standard cursor syntax. The "types" you list here apply only to the T-SQL specific syntax which is built on OLEDB technology and is only available in SQL Server. These "types" specify how the T-SQL cursor handles the rows in memory. If you don't specify, you get a dynamic cursor which may not be be best choice if you are dealing with a small set of rows and you are not concerned with changes made to the rows while your cursor is open.